# Epplus: How to apply a style from the Excel Style Gallery to an ExcelRange

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

The screenshot shows a scenario for a dataset exported by Epplus to a fresh Excel file (file type *.xlsx).

In this scenario, I'd like to apply the "Bad" Style in the Excel Style Gallery to Cell E1. How could I do this programatically in Epplus?

[image: Screenshot of example scenario]

I have looked through the instructional documents I was able to find, [here](https://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ) and [here](https://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ContentSheetExample). I have not yet found an example showing how to apply an Excel style from the Style Gallery to an Excel Range.

Here is what I have so far.

```
private void FormatDataTable(ExcelWorksheet worksheet)
{            
    if(RowCount==0) 
    {
        // How do I apply the "Bad" style to this range?
        var range = worksheet.Cells["E1"];      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know it's no way. But always exists way around

```
var cell = worksheet.Cells["E1"];
cell.Style.Font.Name = "Calibri";
cell.Style.Font.Size = 11;
cell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ffc7ce"));
cell.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
cell.Font.Color.SetColor(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#be0006"));
```

This should make the trick.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. At least I'm not missing something obvious.

Comment: I suggested an edit using the background and text color based on Gimp's measurement of the "Bad" style colors, converting from hex code.

Answer (score 4):

EPPlus supports named styles. The predefined Excel styles are not readily available, unfortunately. It is however fairly easy to recreate them.

Defining a named style can be done like this:

```
ExcelNamedStyleXml ns = workBook.Styles.CreateNamedStyle("Good");
ns.Style.Font.Name = "Calibri";
ns.Style.Font.Family = 2;
ns.Style.Font.Size = 11;
ns.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(0xFF, 0x00, 0x61, 0x00);
ns.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
ns.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(0xFF, 0xC6, 0xEF, 0xCE);
```

In order to apply it to a range, you can just use

```
workSheet.Cells[2, 2].StyleName = "Good";
```

To get the same style as in Excel, create a new workbook, with your favourite styles applied to a couple of cells. It is possible to unzip the saved .xlsx file. It has a `xl/styles.xml` file in it with all the styles that were used. It's quite obvious how to discover the elements needed to recreate the styles.

The `<cellStyles>` node has all the styles. Each `<cellStyle>` node in it has a `name` and `xfId` attribute. The `xfId` refers to a style in the `<cellXfs>` node, where the several elements are combined to form the style. E.g., the `fontId` attribute refers to the *n*-th font in the `<fonts>` node.

Answer (score 0):

To modify only background color use:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

and apply to range

```
sheet.Cells["A1:BB1"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Red);
```